# Connectivity issues after VPN disconnect: Ping but no DNS

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

**PROBLEM**

I often use NordVPN on my linux machine (20.04.1), which uses the `systemd-resolve` network manager. After I disconnect from the VPN, I often have connectivity issues:

- I CAN ping 8.8.8.8
- I CANNOT ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) - which leads me to think this is a DNS issue.

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**

I have tried restarting my network manager: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`, with no change in situation.
My `/etc/resolv.conf` file has the following entries, as the loopback address apparently points to the systemd-resolve service:

/etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53 
options edns0 trust-ad
```

I have tried adding the nameservers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` to the conf file but no solutions.
Restarting the machine does fix the issue until I reuse the VPN, and re-connecting to the VPN always restores my ping to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). But this is not a sustainable solution.

Basically NordVPN is giving me grief, and I may have to go straight to them for support. But any suggestions here for DNS quick-fixes would be appreciated!

Comment: I would be getting support from NordVPN.

Comment: I don't know why, but I keep paying for Nord. I've found their Linux support lacking. Instead, I use their browser plugins and those tend to work quite well. Really, I think I just stick with them because I already have it set up to just auto-renew and because I never really need a VPN outside of the browser.